# Colour command showing side effect upon subsequent text

Tags: function

I introduced colour to a QED command, but the colour has side effect on the text that follows it.  I want the colour to be restricted to the symbol only.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{0,0,139}
\colorlet{celestk}{dblue}

\NewDocumentCommand{\wvQed}{O{celestk}o}
  {
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\color{#1}}{\color[#1]{#2}}
    \hfill\nabla
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Tantra is an Expansion Device. \wvQed

The word appears in the hymns of the Rigveda such as in 10.71

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are also missing `$`. As requested before, please make sure your code compiles and please link and attribute when you use code provided by others. Strictly speaking, this is a legal requirement of SE's licence. (Though I don't know how much would be considered subject to copyright.)

Comment: You  have already been shown how to use a group or \textcolor to scope color, you would find it easier to find existing answers if you did not delete your account aftereach question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expl3` syntax isn't doing much for you here except saving the need to comment line endings. While that's convenient, I wouldn't change category codes for it.

You need `$` to compile this. You need a group to limit the effect of the colour change.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{0,0,139}
\colorlet{celestk}{dblue}

\NewDocumentCommand{\wvQed}{O{celestk}o}
  {%
    \begingroup
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\color{#1}}{\color[#1]{#2}}%
      \hfill$\nabla$%
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}

Tantra is an Expansion Device. \wvQed

The word appears in the hymns of the Rigveda such as in 10.71

\end{document}
```

[image: limited colouration]